# PHP directing to error 404 not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 files time.html and time.php. I am trying to show server date and users date(I use JS for this) in time.html. In php I create random number from 1 to 5 and if number is equal or greater than 3, php should wait 5s then show error 404.

NOTE: if random is smaller than 3 everything works perfectly

PHP:

```
<?php

 $rnd = rand(1, 5);
 if ($rnd >= 3) {
 sleep(5);
 header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
 }
 if ($rnd < 3) {
   sleep(3);
   $tz = date_default_timezone_get();
   date_default_timezone_set($tz);
   $time = date('d.m.Y H:i:s');
   echo "Timezone: " . $tz . ". On date: " . $time;
}
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'time.php',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("span").text(data);
                    }
                });
                document.getElementById("jsTime").innerHTML += Date();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when server responds with an error, jquery.ajax runs the error function, which means your success function does not run. See error on api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'time.php',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("span").text(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqxhr){
                      //redirect to 404 page on 404 error
                      if(jqxhr.status == 404){
                        window.location.href="HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found";
                      }
                    }
                });
                document.getElementById("jsTime").innerHTML += Date();
            });
        });
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work. When is random number greater or equal to 3, my html file looks the same, it does nothing

Comment: @mihcc that is because when server responds with an error, jquery.ajax runs the error function, which means your success function does not run.

See error on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: so i should add something like :
                        error: function () {
                        // what should i put here?;
                    });
                }

Comment: I edited the answer so i can put the code snippet for redirecting on error.

Answer (score 1):

As said, when the server returns an error and the request fails, Jquery Ajax let you handle this error with the error function;

Try to add a couple of options more in the settings:

- add the `error` function.
- add the `statusCode` object and play with it; This lets you have more structured control over the error handling.

So:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'time.php',
        success: function (data) {
            console.info('success');
            $("span").text(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.info(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.info(jqXHR.status);
            console.info(textStatus);
            console.info(errorThrown);
            $("span").text(jqXHR.responseText);
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                alert( "page not found" );
            }
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("jsTime").innerHTML += Date();
});
```

and modify the if inside the php file:

```
if ($rnd >= 3) {
    sleep(1);
    echo "my response text";
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Damn, Not Found"); //just for playing, then keep with HTTP standard description
}
```

Quoting the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation:

> **error**
>
> **Type:** Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ) A
>   function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array
>   of functions. Each function will be called in turn.
>
> **Note:** *This handler
>   is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the data to jquery in array like

1. $str[0]=true/false;
2. $str[1]="HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"/"Timezone: " .$tz . ". On date: ".$time

In success check the condition

```
success: function (data) {
 if(data[0]==true){
 $("span").text(data[1]);
  }else{
window.location.href="HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found";
}
```

i think so ajax call must be completed to redirect, above code works in my machine